# How to search specific HashTags using twitter api 1.1 in Grails Controller

Tags: grails, twitter

I am using twitter 1.1 api,i have created app on twitter, and got authToken,secret and Appid ,Now I want to access twits using HashTag.
Please help me how to use auth token and secret for retrieve twit using HashTag in Grails.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Spring Social Twitter](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) library, it have all you need to access Twitter API.

For your case it will be something like:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
SearchResults results = twitter.searchOperations().search("#spring");
```

See docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#twitter-search

To add this library as a dependency put following into your `BuildConfig`:

```
mavenRepo "http://maven.springframework.org/release"
```

and:

```
compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.0.5.RELEASE'
```

See docs for Grails dependency config: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy

Comment: I have added Social twitter successfully,consumerKey and consumerSecret in config.groovy.And copy paste two lines of code as you provide,but there are no class to import Twitter and SearchResults.So it is giving error in code of lines.